Reference another notebook in a notebook
I am using mkdocs to build my static website. The tree of my project is the following:
docs/
├── index.md
├── numerical_methods
│   └── ode
│       ├── explicit_euler.ipynb
│       └── implicit_euler.ipynb
└── numerical_methods.md

I want add a link to redirect from explicit_euler.ipynb to implicit_euler.ipynb. I added this part [the backward Euler method](./numerical_methods/ode/implicit_euler.ipynb) in explicit_euler.ipynb and it is not redirecting to the other notebook.
If it can help, mkdocs.yml:
site_name: Learning Site
site_dir: public

nav:
  - Home: index.md
  - Numerical Methods: numerical_methods.md

theme: 
  name: material
  icon:
      logo: material/book

  language: en
  features:
    - navigation.tabs
    - content.code.annotate
  palette:
    # Palette toggle for light mode
    - scheme: default
      toggle:
        icon: material/brightness-7
        name: Switch to dark mode

    # Palette toggle for dark mode
    - scheme: slate
      toggle:
        icon: material/brightness-4
        name: Switch to light mode
  plugins:
    - typeset

markdown_extensions:
  - pymdownx.arithmatex:
      generic: true

extra_javascript:
  - javascripts/mathjax.js
  - https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6
  - https://unpkg.com/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js

plugins:
  - search
  - mkdocs-jupyter:
      include_source: True




Yes, because path is wrong. When you are writing your markdown in explicit_euler.ipynb, the ./ part means you are saying to stay in ode, which is wrong because then the rest of the path after that, i.e. numerical_methods/ode/..., is not specifying the correct location of implicit_euler.ipynb relative to explicit_euler.ipynb. So instead you can use [the backward Euler method](./implicit_euler.ipynb) or [the backward Euler method](../../numerical_methods/ode/implicit_euler.ipynb).

That goes way back, see here and here for posts and answers already covering this more generally.

Both answers did not work. I tried both paths. As I build the mkdocs website and go to explicit_euler.ipynb clicking on the referene link redirect to a 404 error.

Hover over the address and copy the link and paste it in a text editor. Examine it. Is it what we expected for it to result in? Sometimes the URLs are processed to make them match the domain. Is that happening? In other words, maybe the relative URL is getting altered to be longer and/or absolute?
